# How do I convert a PHP foreach output into a string?

Tags: php, string, foreach, explode

```
    function Foo($word) { 
        $lowerword= strtolower($word);
        $words = explode(" ", $lowerword);
        foreach ($words as $wrd){
                echo $wrd[0];
            }
    }

$word = "my name is";
$firstletters = Foo($word);
```

Source code above. The idea is to take the first letter from each word in a sentence and piece  them together as one string that can then be further manipulated. However, I am having difficulty manipulating the output, making me think that the output is not really one string. How do I convert the output of the foreach loop into a string?

Answer (score 1):

The output is not a string at all indeed. Your function does `echo` but doesn't return anything.

Try this function:

```
function Foo($word) { 
    $lowerword= strtolower($word);
    $words = explode(" ", $lowerword);
    $firstLetters = '';
    foreach ($words as $wrd){
            $firstLetters .= $wrd[0];
        }
    return $firstLetters;
}
```